# Insert into a different Access.accdb select from SQL Server linked table

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access 2010 database with tables linked to a SQL Server 2008R2 back end.

I need to select records from a linked table and insert them into a *different* Access .accdb, that has a local table.

This is the code I have:

```
Const DbPath = "L:\path\"
Const DbBaseName = "FileTransfer OnSite"
Const DbExt = ".accde"
Const LockDbExt = ".laccdb"
Const ConString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq="

Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim DbOutName As String
Dim DbInName As String
Dim Overwrite As Integer
Dim PutStr As String

'do some sanity checking first, then
FileCopy DbInName, DbOutName    'make a physical copy of the blank on-site file
Set Con = New ADODB.Connection
Con.ConnectionString = ConString & DbOutName
Con.Open

PutStr = "INSERT INTO [;Database=" & DbOutName & "].[Loan] (Loan, FromFirm, ToFirm, Borrower, PropStreet, PropCity, PropState, PropZip, Judicial, Examiner) " & _
    "SELECT Loan, FromFirm, ToFirm, Borrower, PropStreet, PropCity, PropState, PropZip, Judicial, Examiner " & _
    "  FROM Loans " & _
    " WHERE FromFirm = '" & Me.cmbFrom & "' " & _
    "   AND ToFirm = '" & Me.cmbTo & "'"
Set RS = Con.Execute(PutStr)
```

Note that [;Database=...].[Loan] is a local table to the destination database, and that `FROM Loans` references the externally linked table in the source db (the one where this code is running).

PutStr resolves to: (Edited for privacy of the companies involved)

```
INSERT INTO [;Database=L:\Path\FileTransfer OnSite-E-A.accde].[Loan] (Loan, FromFirm, ToFirm, Borrower, PropStreet, PropCity, PropState, PropZip, Judicial, Examiner)
SELECT Loan, FromFirm, ToFirm, Borrower, PropStreet, PropCity, PropState, PropZip, Judicial, Examiner
  FROM Loans
 WHERE FromFirm = 'E'
   AND ToFirm = 'A'
```

I get an error message on the `Set RS =` line stating:

```
Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37)':
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access
database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Loans'. Make
sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.
```

`Loans` is defined in Access as an externally linked table to a SQL Server back end. Other code in the db is working just fine accessing this table. One thing that I thought of, is that the table `Loans` is not in the default schema in SQL Server, but as far as I can tell, Access doesn't care at this point. I can select from `Loans` elsewhere, since the schema info is contained in the link - Access just knows it as `Loans`. I did try referencing `Loans` as `[schema].[Loans]`, but Access didn't like that, either.

I'm not sure why Access can't find the table `Loans` that is defined in the DB where the code is running. I supposed I could break this up into a SELECT from Loans, then a loop to insert into the external .accdb, but I'd rather do it cleanly in a single query if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Access database, I have a linked table named *web_links* which is an ODBC link to a SQL Server table.  So this query retrieves all that table's data:

```sql
SELECT
    l.link_id,
    l.date_added,
    l.url,
    l.notes
FROM web_links AS l;
```

And I have another Access db file named *database2.accdb*.  That db contains a native Access table which is named *web_links*.

So from my current Access db (the one where I successfully ran the `SELECT` query above), I can retrieve the data from SQL Server and append those data to the table in *database2.accdb*.

```sql
INSERT INTO web_links
    (
        link_id,
        date_added,
        url,
        notes
    ) IN 'C:\share\Access\database2.accdb'
SELECT
    l.link_id,
    l.date_added,
    l.url,
    l.notes
FROM web_links AS l;
```

The key point is that Access lets me conveniently indicate the location of the database which will receive the appended data:

```sql
IN 'C:\share\Access\database2.accdb'
```

As best I can tell, this description is similar to what you're trying to accomplish.  And if I got that right, you shouldn't need to bother with ADO, connections strings, objects, and so forth.  Just execute a query which tells the db engine where to find the destination database.

Comment: Excellent, @HansUp! Thank you. Now, I just need to figure out what's causing Access not to like the file name I'm writing to, and all will be good.  The output name is: `"L:\Default\Default Management\Attorney Oversight\Projects\Firm Transfers\Code\FileTransfer OnSite-Lawye R. Name, P.A.-Other & Firm, P.A..accde"`. If I change the output file to "test.accde" your answer worked perfectly, this file name is giving me `Run-time error '3126': Invalid bracketing of name ...` It gives me that error whether the file is enclosed in single-quotes (' ') or brackets ([ ]).

Comment: With all those punctuation characters in the file name, I don't think the approach I suggested can work.  You would have to use a different name which that code can handle, and rename the db after it's done.  That should work, but not sure how much you will like it.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Fortunately, this is a one-time write as I set up an off-site copy of some of the data.  Thanks, HansUp, exactly the guidance I needed